# What is kafka's best synchronous producer response time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have setup a three node kafka cluster and created a topic with replication factor 3. We are producing data to this cluster and we are seeing some messages are taking more than 50ms. On analysing further we found that there is delay in getting response from the broker since we have set producer.acks to all.

On increasing `num.replica.fetchers` from 1 to 4, we see some improvement. But there also for every 150 messages, 1 message is exceeding 50ms and we are using synchronous producer. But when `num.replica.fetchers` is 1, for every 100 messages, 1 message is exceeding 50ms.

Per minute we are producing 500k messages to our cluster.

Our machine configuration:

```
RAM: 8 GB
Hard disk type: HDD
No. of processors: 32
```

Whether this is the optimized time of kafka producer? Whether we need to tune any property to get minimum latency.

Also, what is the best minimal time to produce if we have `producer.acks` as all.

Answer (score 0):

You could try compression or reducing the batch size amount to make request sizes smaller, therefore quicker, in theory

I don't particularly see a need for acks to be set to all.

You could set replication factor to 3, min in sync replicas as 2, then acks as 1, and you'll have a fairly good chance of not losing any data should a broker go down.

One other solution would be just run the producer code on the broker or a machine that's physically connected to the same switch as them in order to reduce network latency.